# strange session problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this field in my session class:

```
public bool IsCartRecentlyUpdated
{
    get
    {
        if (this.session["IsCartRecentlyUpdated"] != null)
        {
            return (bool)this.session["IsCartRecentlyUpdated"];
        }
        else
        {
            this.session["IsCartRecentlyUpdated"] = false;
            return (bool)this.session["IsCartRecentlyUpdated"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.session["IsCartRecentlyUpdated"] = value;
    }
}
```

Whenever a user adds a product to the cart I put this value on true:

```
  public void AddToCart(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        IsCartRecentlyUpdated = true;
     //other code for updating the cart
     }
```

Adding a product to the cart does a postback so I can **show a message** (ëg: *Product added succesfully*) in Page_Load of the General Master page where the shopping cart is located, when a product has just been added to the cart:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.sessionsUtil.IsCartRecentlyUpdated)
    {
        this.lblCartWarning.Text = (string)GetLocalResourceObject("CartWarning");
        imgCardLogos.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblCartWarning.Text = String.Empty;
        imgCardLogos.Visible = true;
    }
//other code
//put it back to false to not show the message each time the page is loaded
this.sessionsUtil.IsCartRecentlyUpdated = false;
}
```

Well this code **works** great **locally** but on the *server* it does not *show the message* after adding the product to the cart but *on the second page loading*...
(I guess that on the server somehow the page is loading before the session var is updated - extremely strange)

Do you know why? I do not see any problem in the code...

Comment: Are you using InProc Session and is you main site hosted by multiple servers sitting behind a load balancer?

Comment: What happens when you add a product? Who sets the session value, who does the postback, what's the order?

Comment: Could it be the server(s) are in a web farm, and your dev environment it not a web farm?

Comment: I use a shared web hosting from https://www.unoeuro.com/ so I cannot see their settings for session but for sure I have nothing specified in web.config regarding this.

Comment: Where do you call the addToCart ?

Comment: @Cristian: Try adding a sessionStage element in your web.config with mode as SQLServer and configure your SQL for the Session Storing.

Comment: Relatively easy way to determine if it's a load balance issue - try repeating this several times. If it never varies from success on the second attempt then it points to (but is not definitely) your issue - go check with IIS express - if it sometimes gives success on first or third or anything variable then it strongly suggetss a load balancer in the way. Ask your provider for sticky sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Strange issues like this might be easier to solve using IIS express
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/03/vs-2010-sp1-beta-and-iis-developer-express.aspx